# Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to push an item to an array every 5 seconds in an AngularJS service, but I keep getting 'items is not defined' after 1 item is added dynamically...

I've been playing with this simple code for over an hour now, I'm sure it's something silly but I can't figure it out. :/

```
app.service('ItemService', function() {

  var items = [9000];

  this.addItem = function () {
    items.push(Math.random());
  }

  setInterval(this.addItem(), 5000);

  return {
    get: function() {
      return items;
    }
  }
});
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/EVFUww7dfUAJzQqth7mx

Comment: try `this.items.push()`...

Comment: @SearchAndResQ why is that wrong? its a new array with 9000 in it?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ - It isn't *wrong* - It creates an array with one item at index:0 with value 9000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using angular, so you shouldn't be doing `setInterval`, but rather use the `$interval` service provided by Angular.

That, coupled with the correct observation of @techfoobar, would result in the correct behavior you are looking for:

```
app.service('ItemService', ['$interval', function($interval) {

  var items = [9000];

  this.addItem = function () {
    items.push(Math.random());
  }

  $interval(this.addItem, 5000); 

  return {
    get: function() {
      return items;
    }
  }
}]);
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jZWjTrXFo7KLPPVmgu2H?p=preview).

Comment: Ahh, you are right! Never knew about $interval as I'm new to Angular. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `addItem()` and passing its return value to `setInterval()` - instead of the function itself.

It should be:

```
setInterval(this.addItem, 5000); // no () after addItem
```

Comment: Close, but not the full answer. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 0):

try using $interval() service instead of setInterval

```
$interval($scope.item, "time_interval");
```

Answer (score 0):

Timing function like window.setInterval, in angularjs are wrapped in $interval (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).
Angular manages interval function like a promise to ensure more control over timer.